# list match head :: tail; I wanna treat head as List, like tail

Tags: scala

I want a recursive function, which removes the consecutive elements "one" and "a".
Is there a way, that i can treat head as a list, like tail, so it doesn't matter where in the list "one" and "a" occures?

````
def reduc(list: List[String]): List[String] = {
  list match {
    case "one" :: "a" :: tail => reduc(tail)
    case head :: "one" :: "a" :: tail => reduc(head :: tail)
    case _ => list
  }
}

reduc(List("one", "one", "a", "a", "b", "c", "one", "a", "c")).mkString(" ")```


expected output: 
b c c

actual:
b c one a c
````

Comment: Your second match is wrong and you need an extra parameter to keep track of new list you will be building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done without pattern matching.

```
def reduc(list: List[String]): List[String] = {
  val index = list.indexOfSlice(List("one","a"))
  if (index < 0) list
  else reduc(list.patch(index,List(),2))
}
```

testing:

```
reduc(List("one", "one", "a", "a", "b", "c", "one", "a", "c"))  
//res0: List[String] = List(b, c, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

A tail recursive version using pattern matching and an extra parameter as @Luis noted in comments to accumulate the results:

```
def reduc(list: List[String]): List[String] = {
  def reducR(list: List[String], acc: List[String]): List[String] = list match {
      case Nil                                         => acc
      case head::tail if(head != "a" && head != "one") => reducR(tail, head::acc)
      case head::tail                                  => reducR(tail, acc)
    }
  reducR(list, List()).reverse
}
```

Comment: What you've got is, essentially, `.filter(x => x != "a" && x != "one")` but what the OP appears to require is the removal of `"one", "a"` **only** if they are consecutive and in that order.

Comment: I was going off the expected output `b c c`. If the goal is "consecutive elements "one" and "a"" then `reduc(List("one", "one", "a", "a"))` would return List("one", "a") since only the middle elements are removed for example. That was my understanding.

Comment: A new `"one","a"` pair is created after the middle elements are removed. It's an iterative procedure that continues until there are no more to be removed. Notice that the OP **wants** (but can't have) the pattern `head::"one"::"a"::tail` match _everything-before::one::a::everything-after_ and then recurses on _everything-before-and-after_.